# read and write in mpi c++ visual 2010

Tags: c++, file, mpi

I have some problem in reading and writing text files in c++ (visual 2010) when my code is in mpi structure. I dont know how open files (text files) and read them. please introduce an example code with text file that do this work .... thank you.

this id my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int iMax = 121;
const int jMax = 35;
const int N=2;
const int BBx = (iMax-1)/N;

struct S_cell{
    double xc, yc;
}cell[BBx+1][jMax];

int main(int argc ,char *argv[] )
{   
    int mpi_rank ,mpi_size;
    MPI_Init(&argc ,& argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD , & mpi_size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD , & mpi_rank);
    int i,j;    
    double XXX, YYY;

    fstream grid;
    grid.open("Grid.plt");
    for(int j=0; j<jMax; j++)
    for(int i=0+BBx*mpi_rank; i<(mpi_rank+1)*BBx+1; i++)
        {
            grid>>XXX>>YYY;
            cell[i-mpi_rank*BBx][j].xc = XXX;
            cell[i-mpi_rank*BBx][j].yc = YYY;

        }
    j=10;
    for(int i=0+BBx*mpi_rank; i<(mpi_rank+1)*BBx+1; i++)
    cout<<cell[i-mpi_rank*BBx][j].yc<<"   "<<mpi_rank<<endl;
    MPI_Finalize();

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Just a head's up. Your question has some problems with it that can be addressed by referring to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Good luck!

Comment: Trying opening a file without using anything from the MPI API, and then try to do it with multiple processes.  Show the code you are having a problem with and what it is, isn't doing.

Comment: MPI does not used shared memory, i.e., cell is instantiated on each process with a different address in memory. Therefore, cell will be different on each process and merging them requires calls to MPI routines. Take a look at some MPI tutorials online (e.g., https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/)

It is unclear what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank .... I want read data of my grid file... because I have used domain decomposition....I searched but I need help yet.

Answer (score 1):

Reading files in an MPI code is the same as normal, however each process will attempt to read the file. A typical use case is to have one input file for each process. As an example, let's say we are running on for processes (`mpirun -np 4 ./exe`). Then we would have four input files, say:

```
input_0.txt
input_1.txt
input_2.txt
input_3.txt
```

To read the files in main do the following:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  int myrank = 0;
  MPI_Comm comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;

  // Initialize MPI and get the process rank
  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm,&myrank);

  // Build the filename for the given process
  std::string filename = "input_" + myrank + ".txt";

  // Open the file stream and read or write
  std::ifstream in(filename.c_str());
  read_file(in);
  in.close();

  // Finalize MPI and exit
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

Some notes:

- My understanding is that the new MPI standard has deprecated the C++ bindings, so it is best to use the C MPI interface.

  If you want all processes to read different information from the same file, then your `read_file` function needs to handle this properly and will be more complex.

  It is perfectly fine to have multiple processes reading the same file, so long as they are not modifying it as well.

  Parallel I/O to a single file is typically implemented by using a library (Google "MPI parallel I/O", etc.).

Comment: The new MPI standard **deleted** the C++ bindings. The older MPI-2.2 deprecated them in favour of the C interface and 3rd party C++ interfaces like Boost.MPI.